# Remove validation errors without submitting the form again

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a JSP which has multiple sections in the form of tabs. When clicking the next button the form is validated and error messages are displayed as per the validation. Now when I move to a different tab, the earlier error messages are still there on tab 2 and are only removed when clicking next again.

Is there any way that when I switch to a different section within the same form, I could remove earlier validation errors without submitting the form again

Thanks

Comment: Try this option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672029/2812842

Comment: How are the error messages stored? How are they persisting across web pages? Show us some of the code in question so that we can understand the issue.